# remove first and last chevron in ng-bootstrap carousel (Angular7 app)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I've been trying to figure out how to hide the first and last chevron in a ng-bootstrap carousel. I can't seem seem to remove the :first and :last child as per the more vanilla bootstrap/ jquery way that is well documented here on SO. Any ideas? (please see attached link to a stackblitz)

I've tried hacking via css/ styles in the typescript file but to no avail

[a link] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-izpi67?file=app/carousel-basic.ts) - updated link!

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
[showNavigationArrows]="showNavigationArrows"
```

in component

```
showNavigationArrows = false;


<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images" [showNavigationArrows]="showNavigationArrows" [showNavigationIndicators]="showNavigationIndicators">....
```

ref: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api

updated url:

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-izpi67-wnflxd?file=app/carousel-basic.ts
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but that just removes the icons entirely - I only want to remove the first left and last right icon of an array of images like so - * img >/ < img > / < img> / < img > / < img  * - if that makes any sense